# Which nWoD books mention Detroit?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

Which new World of Darkness books talk about Detroit? I know at least one book mentions the city, I'm not sure if it's more than that.

Answer (score 2):

A write-up of Detroit can be found in **Saturnine Night** for *Promethean: the Created,* page 110-119, leading to "These Mortal Engines," the conclusion of the "Waters of Life" Chronicle.

Comment: Water of Life takes place in Chicago

Comment: I didn't find any mention of it it PtC, page number?

Comment: Updated with page numbers.